# Can't access AWS services/setup after account creation: "Signature not yet current"

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, synchronization, account

I recently created an AWS account. I get error messages everywhere, and can't do anything. The problem seems to be that I'm out of synch with AWS time by more than 5 minutes, which seems to be the maximum discrepancy time. I set Windows to automatic time and automatic time zone, assuming this could help, but it did not.

This is the most detailed message I get:

> Signature not yet current: 20230325T212317Z is still later than 20230325T212145Z (20230325T211645Z + 5 min.)

I think those numbers indicate the date and time, going all the way to the second and fraction of a second.

1. Am correctly reading those timestamps?
   and most importantly,
2. How do I fix this?

Can anybody please give me some suggestions? I'm not an experienced developer. Please try to be as explicit as possible. Thank you.

I tried setting both the time and time zone to automatic, as I read in other posts that this could solve the problem. But it did not.

Comment: You may need to [force Windows to time sync](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+time+force+resync).

Comment: Just set Windows to the time shown on your watch/phone and make sure it is set to the correct Timezone. That will make it close enough.

Comment: jarmod and John Rotenstein, your suggestions worked. All error messages are gone, and I can start working on my first AWS EC2 instance. Thank you!